# Laravel 5.6 "failed to open stream: Permission denied in filesystem.php"

Tags: linux, laravel, redhat

I upload my laravel 5.6 project on Linux Server but the website is not running in the browser and I am getting the given error. Please Help.

[image: error]

Comment: please a look on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#configuration. In addition this might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/file-permissions-for-laravel-5-and-others

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The framework is unable to create a cache of the views from the looks of the logs. You need to update the permissions on the `storage` folder.

If the `storage` folder is owned by a different user to your server software (i.e. user is not `www-data`), you need to set the permissions using:

```
chmod -R 777 storage
```

If the `storage` folder is owned by `www-data` (or the appropriate system user for your server software), you can use the less open:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

If you run into permission issues, you may need to prefix the above commands with `sudo`.

Comment: Sorry but its not working with me. Same error and getting the same msg on the browser: This page isn’t working.

Comment: Ohh thanks i think it works when i added one more command into this: php artisan view:clear

Comment: NEVER use 777 permissions. See stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/470749